# Cocoapods: 'pod install' fails with Xcodeproj relies on a library called `fiddle` to read and write Xcode project files

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, rbenv

I've just downloaded an iOS/objective-c project from github which uses Cocoapods for its dependencies.

When I attempt to `pod install` in the terminal I receive the following error:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Xcodeproj relies on a library called `fiddle` to read and write Xcode project files. Ensure your Ruby installation includes `fiddle` and try again.
```

So I installed fiddle using `gem install fiddle` which succeeded successfully and if I now perform a `gem list` it would appear that `fiddle (0.6.3)` is successfully installed. Addtionally I can see a `/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fiddle-0.6.3/` directory.

However when I try to `pod install` I get the exact same error as before.

If it makes any difference, I am using RBENV.

Can anyone help?  I've googled the error to try and resolve myself but the only results I get are the source code for the Cocoapods/Xcodeproj project that outputs the error itself.

Some further info incase it helps:

```
which ruby
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

.

```
pod install --verbose
  Preparing

Updating local specs repositories

Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     194b47f..be34c13  master     -> origin/master
  Updating 194b47f..be34c13
  Fast-forward
   .../0.1.2/Backgroundable.podspec.json              | 21 +++++++++++++++++
   .../1.0.0/ToolTipNavigation.podspec.json           | 27 ++++++++++++++++++++++
   2 files changed, 48 insertions(+)
   create mode 100644 Specs/Backgroundable/0.1.2/Backgroundable.podspec.json
   create mode 100644 Specs/ToolTipNavigation/1.0.0/ToolTipNavigation.podspec.json

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
[!] Xcodeproj relies on a library called `fiddle` to read and write Xcode project files. Ensure your Ruby installation includes `fiddle` and try again.


/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.26.3/lib/xcodeproj/plist_helper.rb:7:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.26.3/lib/xcodeproj/plist_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.26.3/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:32:in `compute_results'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:655:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `each'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:652:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:61:in `analyze'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:210:in `analyze'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:133:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:132:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:104:in `install!'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed.  I installed a newer version of ruby and all is well in the world.

(I am unsure whether it was actually a newer version or whether it was merely a fresh install that sorted things)

Here are the commands I ran in case it helps...

```
brew update
brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
rbenv install 2.2.2
rbenv global 2.2.2
rbenv rehash
gem install cocoapods
pod install
```